# Routing with expressjs app.post({}).delete({}) not working the second one

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm facing an issue and I don't know how solve it, I'm not and expert with nodejs + expressjs, but in this case I think I'm doing all wright!

Well, the problem is that when I add different methods in an endpoint, like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/myRoute', function (req, res){
             //all the thing
             res.json(msg: 'some msg here');
    })
       .delete('/myRoute', function (req, res){
             //all the thing
             res.json(msg: 'some msg here');
    });
```

in the app.js I'm including all the routes:

```
var app = express(),
routePath = path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'routes', path.sep);


fs.readdirSync(routePath).forEach(function(file) {
    var route = routePath + file;
    require(route)(app);
});
```

Now, I can reach (with rest client) the endpoint which use the post method, but not when it use the delete method (getting a 500 Internal Server Error 'Response does not contain any data.').

I dont know what is happening.... some ideas?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Your JavaScript syntax looks invalid

Comment: mmm yes but the gulp-jshint doesn't mark as invalid or something like that, I tried like this:

app.post({});
app.delete({}); 

and same result

Answer (score 1):

The reason why chaining works in jQuery is because every function returns the element in use, Express does not do this for you, so you will have to separate the blocks out, or try and improve express to return the app object. To solve this problem you simply need to add another `app` variable.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/myRoute', function (req, res){
         //all the thing
         res.json({msg: 'some msg here'});
    })
    app.delete('/myRoute', function (req, res){
         //all the thing
         res.json({msg: 'some msg here'});
    });
}
```

Comment: Sry, but is working now! the problem was an error with mongoose inside delete endpoint...

About your answer, my project works chaining methods, thanks anyway man! I appreciate all your answers!

Comment: interesting, mine do not always

Answer (score 0):

You can use app.route for chaining

```
app.route('/myRoute')
.post(function (req, res){
     //post action
})
.delete(function (req, res){
     //delete action
});
```